# how to removing right colon in New page in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want create a single page in codeigniter . in this page already create in template.php side bar. please help and suggest.

this code is used in template.php

```
 <!--.rightcolom--> 
    <?php if (!isset($righ_side)){ 
            $this->load->view('front_view/right_side');
    }?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear you need to add some more details with code to elaborate your problem

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: i want remove in codeigniter default side panel(rightcolom) only one page  .

Comment: Should `$righ_side` be `$right_side`?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to do. Codeigniter doesn't have the default side panel. Codeigniter is just a php framework and you can layout your site the way you want it.